# How can I update the NVIDIA drivers to version 390.77?

Tags: nvidia, updates

I had the NVIDIA drivers and all related software updated to version 390.77 when I was running Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1. Recently I switched back to vanilla Ubuntu 18.04.1, but I don't seem to have the 390.77 drivers installed - the current version installed is 390.48. I was able to get the newer drivers and related software through the Ubuntu MATE repositories. Why can't I get them through the official repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NVIDIA drivers version 390.48 from the official Ubuntu 18.04 repositories are those ones which were current at the time when Ubuntu 18.04 was released. There is a GPU Drivers PPA from which you can install newer versions. Execute the following commands, if you want to install one of them:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-<version>
sudo reboot
```

Replace `<version>` with `390` if you want the latest stable long-lived branch drivers.

Replace `<version>` with `396` if you want the latest stable short-lived branch drivers.

Currently the latest stable drivers from the NVIDIA long-lived branch are 390.77.

Currently the latest stable drivers from the NVIDIA short-lived branch are 396.51.

Addressing the comments that the 390.77 and the 396.51 drivers are not visible -
here is the proof they are (screenshot of the PPA and `apt` after adding the PPA).

[image: GPU Drivers PPA]

```
$ apt policy nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-driver-390:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 390.48-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     390.48-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
$ apt policy nvidia-driver-396
N: Unable to locate package nvidia-driver-396
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update

$ apt policy nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-driver-390:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Version table:
     390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     390.48-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
$ apt policy nvidia-driver-396
nvidia-driver-396:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 396.51-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
  Version table:
     396.51-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: The PPA currently shows version 390.48 as the current long-lived drivers though. At least, from what I see here: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @hiigaran I see versions 390.77 (390.77-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) and 396.51 (396.51-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1).

Comment: Odd. Why am I not seeing that?

Comment: I'm seeing 390.48 as the long-lived driver too.

Comment: @BoJohnson Did you try what I wrote ? Did you try to install the newer drivers the way I have described ? 390.77 and 396.51 drivers are visible **after adding the PPA and updating the repositories**. I've updated the answer with the relevant information. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox I was able to get the 390.77 after adding the graphics-drivers ppa, thanks!